# How to iterate through blocks in a theme region and change markup

Tags: drupal, twig

I want to iterate through all blocks that are placed in a specific region to achieve the following (only within this specific region):

1. Extract their title to output them like that:

```
<ul>
 <li>Title of Block 1</li>
 <li>Title of Block 2</li>
 <li>Title of Block 3</li>
</ul>
```

2. Display their content like that:

```
<div>
 <div>Content of Block 1</div>
 <div>Content of Block 2</div>
 <div>Content of Block 3</div>
</div>
```

Any ideas how I can achieve that?

Comment: Use this : https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/tags/for.html ? 
Does that answer your question?

Comment: @Jboucly: Thanks for you help! My issue is that I do not know in which twig templates to place the loop in Drupal and how to make the variables available so that I could iterate through a) the titles of my blocks and b) the content.